# Retrieve constants from inner in Newtype pattern

Tags: rust

Is there a way to retrieve public constants from the inner struct in the Newtype pattern?

Say I am using a struct from another crate like this

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq)]
pub struct Version(u32);
impl Version {
    pub const v0: Self = Self(0);
    pub const v1: Self = Self(1);
}
```

Now, in my code I need to wrap it with a [newtype](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#using-the-newtype-pattern-to-implement-external-traits-on-external-types) pattern. So far so good.

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq)]
pub struct MyVersion(Version);
```

I want to get the inner constant using the wrapper type along the lines of `MyVersion::v0`. Is this doable?

[Rust Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8ce630caad2a5403472d0a1c22a82e40)

Comment: Only if you re-define them.

Comment: there is no logical reason to allow this, a new type is a ... new type

Comment: Yeah, there are`Deref` traits though that allow exposing members of the inner type. What I need is to have something exposing also the static members.

Comment: Most likely a `PhantomData` + inherent associated types combo would work, but sadly they are still unstable. I could then call `MyVersion::SomeName::v0`.

Comment: You can always redefine them in an `impl MyVersion { pub const v0: Version = Version::v0; … }` assuming there aren't too many.

Comment: Instead of an inherent associated type, you could also use an associated type on a custom trait.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, This will work; the usage ends up somewhat awkward, though, along the lines of `<MyVersion as Versioning>::V::v0`. Otherwise, it complains of `E0223`. Thanks!

Comment: [playground to the above for reference](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a6501678b61deaf0be1f9fa3f051a667)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Sven for suggesting a solution that works with stable Rust.

A way out of this is to implement a trait with an associated type. The end usage is awkward (due to [E0223](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error_codes/E0223.html)), but at least re-defining constants and associated methods is unnecessary.

```rust
// original crate
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct Version(u32);
impl Version {
    pub const V0: Self = Self(0);
    pub const V1: Self = Self(1);
}

// another crate
use std::ops::Deref;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct MyVersion(Version);

impl Deref for MyVersion {
    type Target = Version;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        &self.0
    }
}

trait Versioning {
    type V;
}

impl Versioning for MyVersion {
    type V = Version;
}

fn main() {
    let myv0 = MyVersion(Version::V0);
    
    assert_eq!(*myv0, <MyVersion as Versioning>::V::V0);
}
```

The custom trait will probably not be needed when [inherent associated type](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/8995) lands in the stable channel.